# Error encountered trying to convert string to date time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running this program to convert str into date time:

```
 def _get_date_time(self, date_time):
        parsed = datetime.strptime(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        formatted = parsed.strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %-I:%M %p')
        formatted = formatted.replace('AM', 'a.m.').replace('PM', 'p.m.')
        return formatted
```

But I keep getting this error, which I am confused as to why. Could someone show me what I am missing?

```
ValueError: time data '2021-01-15 18:03:01.208010+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Comment: I think maybe you meant: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00'`

Comment: If you replace the space with "T", you'll get an ISO8601 timestamp. Go look for an ISO8601 library you like, there are a handful of them in PyPI.

Comment: If i skip `self` and fix `%-I` to `%I` then it works fine to my end. Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported datetime module?There might be error if not.
I removed self because I don't know the class you are in.Please have a look at my code

```py
import datetime
def _get_date_time(date_time):
        parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        formatted = parsed.strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')
        formatted = formatted.replace('AM', 'a.m.').replace('PM', 'p.m.')
        print(formatted)
```